# Call subprocess sudo from uwsgi

Tags: python, linux, bash, uwsgi, sudo

I am executing a `sudo` statement from python over uwsgi. I configured the account (`www-data`) to not need a password for `sudo` but it does not work.

If I run from shell, it works properly with the desired account:

```
www-data@srv sudo iptables -L -n
```

but from my script and uwsgi, it prompts for password.

In `sudoers` I have:

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/iptables
```

and in my python script:

```
subprocess.call(['sudo', '/sbin/iptables -L -n'])
```

Thanks and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tested this code on my server, it could be a good alternative :

```
subprocess.call("sudo" + " /sbin/iptables -L -n", shell=True)
```

see https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Answer (score 0):

can you do `subprocess.call('/usr/bin/id')` before your sudo to see if you're executing it as www-data ?

Comment: Yes I already check that with subprocess call and whoami, its www-data. Thanks for the answer and the moderator for edit.